# How to restart countdown timer and why is it skipping seconds

Tags: javascript, html, timer

How can I make it so the timer restarts itself when it hits zero?
Also, I have noticed sometimes it skips so instead of counting 5,4,3,2,1 it would go 5,4,3 1 - so misses out the two - How can I fix this?

```
const startingMinutes = 1;
let time = startingMinutes * 60;

const countdownEl = document.getElementById('countdown');

setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);

function updateCountdown() {
    const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
    let seconds = time % 60;

    seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

    countdownEl.innerHTML = `${minutes}: ${seconds}`;
    time--;
    time = time < 0 ? 0 : time; 

}
```

HTML

```
<p id="countdown"></p>
```

I look forward to your ideas.
Many thanks

Comment: use `clearInterval();`

Comment: Thank you but its not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a reference to your interval

```
var myInterval = setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);
```

Then you can clear it and start a new one

```
clearInterval(myInterval);
myInterval = setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/owt7b9h6/1/

Comment: The original answer definitely reset the interval.  Have you updated the time value back to the starting time?  Have added a fiddle link to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, the timer restarts which is what I wanted.